# Solving $2\cos(x) = \sin(x)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How would you solve equations of the form $ a \sin (x+b) = \sin (x)$?

Eg. $ 2 \cos(x) = \sin(x) $

I realy have no idea how I would solve this kind of equations.

Comment: Especially equations like this one where all terms either have $\cos$ or $\sin$ (with the same argument in them), the easiest way is to divide through by $\cos$ and remember that $\frac{\sin}{\cos} = \tan$.

Comment: Note that @Arthur's suggestion always works because the roots of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are disjoint and thus if the original LHS were zero, the orignial RHS was nonzero and so the equation has no solutions where $\cos(x) = 0$, so division by $\cos(x)$ is justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your initial question, you can use the [angle-sum rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_sum_and_difference_rules#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for $\sin(\alpha + \beta):$ $$\sin(\alpha \pm \beta) = \sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta$$

So $$a \sin (x+b) = \sin (x) \iff a (\sin x \cos b + \cos x \sin b) = \sin x$$

We can divide through by $\cos x$, provided $\cos x \neq 0$, noting that $a, \cos b, \sin b$ are all constants.

---

For your example:

Note that if $\cos x \neq 0$, then $2 \cos x = \sin x \iff 2 = \dfrac {\sin x}{\cos x} = \tan x \iff \tan^{-1}(2) = x$.

And as @Alex notes,  $2\cos x = \sin x \implies \cos x \neq 0$.

Comment: In the second to last line I'm sure you mean $\tan^{-1}(2) = x$ instead of $\tan^{-1}(x) = 2$ :)

Comment: Thanks, @brom! Yes, indeed, that's what I meant!

Answer (score 3):

I would do a [tan half angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) substitution with $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ which leads to
 $$ \cos(x) = \cos\left( 2 \tan^{-1} t \right) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \\
\sin(x) =\sin \left( 2 \tan^{-1} t \right) =\frac{2 t}{1+t^2} $$

which transforms your problem to

$$ \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} a \sin(b) + \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \left(a \cos(b)-1\right) =0 \rightarrow$$

$$ 2 t \left(a \cos b -1\right) + a (1-t^2)\sin b=0  $$

The above has two solutions

$$ \boxed{ t = \dfrac{a\cos b-1 \pm \sqrt{c}}{a \sin b} }$$ where $c=1+a (a-2\cos b) $, and $ \boxed{x= 2 \tan^{-1} t }$.

So with $a=2$ and $b=0$ the result is $x =\pm \pi$

### Notes:

This method allows the transformation of any trigonometric expression into a polynomial expression. it is often used in Robotics.

Answer (score 2):

$$
a\sin(x+b) = a\sin x\cos b + a\sin b\cos x = \sin x \\\\
\implies (a\cos b - 1)\sin x = a\sin b\cos x \\\\
\implies \tan x = \frac{a \sin b}{a\cos b - 1}\\\\
\implies x = \arctan\left(\frac{a \sin b}{a\cos b - 1}\right)$$

Comment: This answer would probably be much more useful to the OP if it had an explanation of the steps.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\cos(x)- \sin(x)=0$$
$$-2\cos(x)+\sin(x)=0$$
$$\sqrt{5}*\sin(x-\arctan{2})=0$$

You can solve it also in this way.